# Listener on EditText inside a CardView inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have a pretty straightforward `RecycleView` controlled by an `adapter`. Each item in the list is a custom object (CharacterModel), displayed in `CardViews`. Each `CardView` displays the fields of the object (like name and hp). I want these fields to be able to change the value. What I want is to know how to setup a listener so that when I click one of the `EditText` I can set the value for that object and that field.

The closest I got was with this tutorial: https://tutorialwing.com/android-recyclerview-tutorial-example/

But that only allows me to identify which `CardView` (which object) I clicked. Not which `EditText` inside that `CardView`.

Comment: Some code would be nice; but why can you not use the views id to determine which edit text is clicked? What exactly are you doing for you listener/click listener

Comment: Well if I follow the tutorial I don't get the EditText view, I get the CardView view.

Comment: Try this tutorial instead: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#attaching-click-handlers-using-listeners

Comment: Add the code for your adapter and the layout for your views; You should ideally be attaching listeners at that layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like that

In your onBindViewHolder add:

```
viewholder.eT_name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocused) {
                if(isFocused)
                {
                   //your action
                }
            }
        });
```